# Laravel Storage::get unable to access after symbolic link created

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, upload, laravel-5.5

The following uploads/moves the file correctly in 5.5 -- able to see/access from directory -- but Storage::get does not return the file path, and even with a symbolic link created, accessing files directly gives 404.

```
$currentuser_id = Auth::user()->id;
$file = request()->file('resume');
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::disk('uploads')->put($currentuser_id.'/'.$fileName, file_get_contents($file));
```

Trying to access the file, $content ends up empty:

```
$content = Storage::disk('uploads')->get($currentuser_id.'/filename.pdf');
```

Accessing file directly produces 404:

https://www.website.com/storage/uploads/1/filename.pdf

Filesystems config:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'uploads' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root'   => storage_path().'/uploads',
    ],

],
```

Comment: can you add the config array for that disk to the post?

Comment: @lagbox sure thing -- added full config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code a little bit by using the methods for dealing with the storage disks that `UploadedFile` provides.

```
$file = request()->file('resume');
$file->storeAs(Auth::id(), $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'uploads');
```

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Requests - Storing Uploaded Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#storing-uploaded-files)

`storage/app/public` might be linked but `storage/uploads` isn't linked in the public folder, so there isn't an accessible address to get the files.

Comment: Wouldn't `php artisan storage:link` allow me to access all subfolders within storage after the symbolic link is created?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had to specifically link `/storage/uploads` to public, not just `/storage` which is what I had originally done. That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: you didn't link `storage`, that command doesn't link `storage`, it links `storage/app/public` which is what the `public` disk points to by default